# Conky update interval now very slow since upgrading to Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: conky, 20.10

Anyone else using Conky with Ubuntu 20.10? Anyone else seeing issues with Conky update_interval since 20.10?

I don't really know if this is an issue with Conky or with Ubuntu but I am trying to debug/solve. I have 3 Ubuntu installations with Conky and previously they would update every second as expected. Since updating to Ubuntu 20.10 they all now exhibit the same behaviour - Conky updating only every 5 or 6 seconds.

I could not find any open or closed issues on Conky github relating to slowdown or the "cpu" variable causing issues so I tried to do a bit of debugging. No errors in the conky log.

I simplified my conky config to show JUST the time with seconds and that works fine (Conky updates every second). So I slowly started adding things to the config until I found that if I have any cpu variable line in my config I get the slow Conky update every 5 or 6 seconds. So for example:
`${hwmon 1 temp 1}`
and/or
`${top cpu 1}`
works fine
but add this:
`${cpu cpu3}`
And I get the slow updates.

BUT if I remove the `lua_load` line in my config then all values (including the CPU values) show correctly and at the correct `update_interval`, so it seems to be some combination of LUA and the cpu variable.

SUMMARY:
No lua_load (just text values including cpu variables) = works ok.
lua_load but no cpu variables = works ok.
lua_load with cpu variables = slow updates.

Information

OS:
Ubuntu 20.10, Gnome 3.38.1 X11
5.8.0-25-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:30:38 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Conky: I am just using the supplied package version which is currently 1.11.6

```
$ conky -V
conky 1.11.6 compiled 2020-08-17 for Linux x86_64

Compiled in features:

System config file: /etc/conky/conky.conf
Package library path: /usr/lib/conky


 General:
  * math
  * hddtemp
  * portmon
  * IPv6
  * IRC
  * Curl
  * RSS
  * ICal
  * iconv
  * Weather (METAR)
  * wireless
  * support for IBM/Lenovo notebooks
  * nvidia
  * builtin default configuration
  * old configuration syntax
  * Imlib2
  * OSS mixer support
  * apcupsd
  * iostats
  * ncurses
  * Internationalization support
  * PulseAudio

 Lua bindings:
  * Cairo
  * Imlib2
  * RSVG
 X11:
  * Xdamage extension
  * Xinerama extension (virtual display)
  * Xshape extension (click through)
  * XDBE (double buffer extension)
  * Xft
  * ARGB visual
  * Own window

 Music detection:
  * Audacious
  * CMUS
  * MPD
  * MOC
  * XMMS2

 Default values:
  * Netdevice: eno1
  * Local configfile: $HOME/.conkyrc
  * Localedir: /usr/share/locale
  * Maximum netdevices: 256
  * Maximum text size: 16384
  * Size text buffer: 256
```

EXAMPLE CONFIG:
Note: If I comment out any of the $cpu variable lines it updates every second as expected. With one or more $cpu variable lines I get the slow update every 5 or 6 seconds.

```
conky.config = {
    alignment               = 'top_right',
    background              = false,
    border_inner_margin         = 0,
    border_outer_margin         = 0,
    border_width            = 0,
    color0              = '772953', 
    color1              = 'EBE1E1',
    cpu_avg_samples             = 2,
    default_color           = 'gray',
    default_outline_color       = 'green',
    default_shade_color         = 'red',
    diskio_avg_samples          = 2,
    double_buffer           = true,
    draw_borders            = false,
    draw_graph_borders          = false,
    draw_outline            = false,
    draw_shades             = false,
    extra_newline           = false,
    font                = 'Play:normal:size=7',
    format_human_readable       = true,
    gap_x               = 30,
    gap_y               = 150,
    lua_load                = '/home/me/Documents/Files/scripts/conky/rings.lua',
    lua_draw_hook_pre           = 'conky_main',
    maximum_width           = 520,
    minimum_width           = 520,
    net_avg_samples             = 2,
    no_buffers              = true,
    out_to_console          = false,
    out_to_stderr           = false,
    extra_newline           = false,
    own_window              = true,
    own_window_argb_visual      = true,
    own_window_class            = 'Conky',
    own_window_type             = 'desktop',
    own_window_transparent      = true,
    own_window_argb_visual      = true,
    override_utf8_locale        = true,
    stippled_borders            = 0,
    temperature_unit            = 'celsius',
    text_buffer_size            = 2048,
    update_interval             = 1.0,
    uppercase               = false,
    use_spacer              = 'none',
    use_xft                 = true,
    show_graph_scale            = false,
    show_graph_range            = false,
    xftalpha                = 0.9,
};

conky.text = [[
${font Play:normal:size=7}${voffset 16}${color1}${goto 120}${freq_g cpu0} Ghz${alignr 330}${hwmon 1 temp 1} °C
#
#${font Play:normal:size=7}${voffset 0}${goto 120}${color1}CPU 1 ${alignr 330}${color1}${cpu cpu0}%
#${font Play:normal:size=7}${voffset 2}${goto 120}${color1}CPU 2${alignr 330}${color1}${cpu cpu1}%
#${font Play:normal:size=7}${voffset 2}${goto 120}${color1}CPU 3${alignr 330}${color1}${cpu cpu2}%
${font Play:normal:size=7}${voffset 2}${goto 120}${color1}CPU 4${alignr 330}${color1}${cpu cpu3}%
${goto 50}${voffset 16}${font Play:normal:size=7}${color1}${top name 1}${alignr 306}${top cpu 1}%
${goto 50}${font Play:normal:size=7}${color1}${top name 2}${alignr 306}${top cpu 2}%
${goto 50}${font Play:normal:size=7}${color1}${top name 3}${alignr 306}${top cpu 3}%
${font Michroma:size=10}${color0}${goto 80}${voffset 4}CPU

${time %I}:${time %M}:${time %S}

]];
```

Comment: I think the cpu info is read from `/proc/stat`, but I'm sure `time cat /proc/stat` will show you can read it quickly. Try `strace -r -o /tmp/out conky` for one cycle to see what system calls are being done around the wait. `-r` adds a relative timestamp to each line.

Comment: I started an issue on the conky github page about this. A couple of others are seeing the same thing but no solution yet: https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/issues/1031